# How to pass data from Django Template to View

Tags: python, django

I have a template where customer details are displayed, along with a 'Create Lead' button at the bottom. This should take the user to the Lead creation form page where the customer field should be pre-selected.

I'm new to django. Based on responses of previous similar questions, I came up with the below code. But when I click the 'Create Lead' button, the url changes from  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sales/customer/21" to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sales/customer/21/?customer_id=21" but nothing happens on the page. I tried with POST method and csrf token also, but it gives HTTP ERROR 405. Could some please help here.

Also, I've separate view for creating a Lead, which is sort of duplication of CreateView for Lead. And I believe that's not how it's supposed to be. What is the way to club them both in single view.

Below are the code snippets.

**Models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Lead(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,related_name='Leads',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    destinations = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    lead_source = models.CharField(max_length=256,choices=lead_source_choices,default='FNF')
    lead_source_id = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True)
    lead_status = models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=lead_status_choices,default='NEW')
    remarks = models.TextField(blank=True)
    trip_id = models.CharField(max_length=10,editable=False,unique=True,default="IN"+uuid.uuid1().hex[:5].upper())
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class LeadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = ('customer','destinations','lead_source','lead_source_id','lead_status','remarks')

class LeadFromCustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = ('destinations','lead_source','lead_source_id','lead_status','remarks')
```

**Template**

```
  <form method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="{{customer.id}}">
    <a href="{% url 'SalesApp:lead_create_from_customer' %}">
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg float-right" type="submit">Create Lead</button></a>
  </form>
```

**Urls.py**

```
path('lead/create/',views.LeadCreateView.as_view(),name='lead_create'),
path('lead/create/customer/',views.LeadCreateFromCustomerView.as_view(),name='lead_create_from_customer')
```

**Views.py**

```
class LeadCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,CreateView):
    form_class = LeadForm
    model = Lead
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.groups.filter(name='Sales').exists()

class LeadCreateFromCustomerView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,CreateView):
    form_class = LeadFromCustomerForm
    model = Lead
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.groups.filter(name='Sales').exists()
    def form_valid(self,form):
        customer_id = self.request.GET.get("value")
        form.instance.customer = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)
        return super(LeadCreateFromCustomerView,self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Your first form should just GET the new form, but it should go to your 'lead_create_from_customer' url, so in the template, change to `<form method="GET" action="{% url 'lead_create_from_customer' %}">`.

Comment: I made the change in the template, and in the LeadCreateFromCustomerView, changed the form_class to LeadForm. Now it's taking me to the Lead creation page. but Customer is not pre-selected.

Comment: That's because you don't pre select it in your `LeadCreateFromCustomerView`. You need to override `get_initial()` to pass initial values to the form.

Comment: I added the 'get_initial()' function to the 'LeadCreateFromCustomerView', but now it gives DoesNotExist error (Customer matching query does not exist.). It is giving the exact same error when I use form_valid() instead. But looking at the url it seems that customer_id (21 in above example) is being passed properly. And there definitely is a customer with that id. Below is the code snippet.

Comment: 'code' def get_initial(self):
        """
        Returns the initial data to use for forms on this view.
        """
        initial = super().get_initial()
        customer_id = self.request.GET.get("value")
        initial['customer'] = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)
        return initial

Comment: First you should never just do `Model.object.get(...)` without being sure the `get()` will work or without wrapping it in a `try... except...`. But the reason is that the query parameter isn't "value" but "customer_id". Look at the `name` attribute of your input and look at the URL query parameters.